# Can I get a value from the last row only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm making a spreadsheet where the cell value determines the number of rows to be inserted next, the problem is that if my first row has "1" and the last one has "2", I want to insert 2 lines next, but it's inserting only 1 line.

And that's why I wanted to get the value of just the last row to add the following rows.

So I'm using the formula:

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet

var secondName = ss.getRange('E10:E').getValue();
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

if (secondName == "1"){
    ss.insertRowsAfter(lastRow,1);
}
```

So it adds 1 row when the column "E" has the number 1.

And to add 2 rows it is:

```
if (secondName == "2"){
    ss.insertRowsAfter(lastRow,2);
}
```

But when I run the function it adds only 1 row following the cell with the value "2", that should add 2 rows.

So I was thinking if it's possible to get the value of the last row only, to insert the right number of rows.

And since I'm not experienced in JavaScript, (it's my first time trying it) I hope my doubt is clear enough.

Can you guys help me out?

(English is not my first language. Sorry for any mistake.)

Comment: Please notice that Java and JavaScript are different languages. Here you're talking about JavaScript. Also, there's no need to repeat the question tags in the title :)

Comment: Use message/alert boxes to see the values of your stuff for example ss.getRange('E10:E').getValue();

Comment: I'm not sure but I think what your asking is, in column E of the last row it has a number that tells how many rows to add after the last row.

Comment: Exactly @TheWizEd!

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple spreadsheet as shown below.  To get the value in the last row of column E, try this.

[image]

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let rows = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),5).getValue();  // column E last row
    console.log("rows to add = "+rows);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

12:14:16 PM Notice  Execution started
12:14:17 PM Info    rows to add = 25
12:14:18 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Tysm for the help